# Insert q record in sql with c#?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Please can you help me with this error message. It is SQL Compact in Visual Studio.

```
"INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ('New1','a','a','a','a','a','Antrim','F',02/02/1971     
 00:00:00,'a','a@aol.com',0,'a',0)"
```

"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 
    80,Token in error = 00 ]"

The file structure is as follows.

```
TABLE [Contact]
[UserName] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
[FirstName] NVARCHAR(30),
[LastName] NVARCHAR(30),
[Address_1] NVARCHAR(30),
[Address_2] NVARCHAR(30),
[Town] NVARCHAR(30),
[County] NVARCHAR(30),
[Gender] NVARCHAR(1),
[DoB] DATETIME,
[Phone] NVARCHAR(30),
[Email] NVARCHAR(30),
[Email_List] BIT,
[Twitter] NVARCHAR(30),
[Twitter_List] BIT
```

Comment: Should the `datetime` value be wrapped in quotes as well?  Mine usually are.  Also, what does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 1):

Your date value isn't in quotes.  Dates are represented as strings.  It should be:

```
'02/02/1971 00:00:00'
```

Full example:

```
"INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ('New1','a','a','a','a','a','Antrim','F', '02/02/1971 00:00:00','a','a@aol.com',0,'a',0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your date time into apostrophes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using quotes for `Datetime` value `'02/02/1971 00:00:00'`:-

```
"INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ('New1','a','a','a','a','a','Antrim','F','02/02/1971     
 00:00:00','a','a@aol.com',0,'a',0)"
```